# SQL Server: the login is from untrusted domain and cannot be used with integrated authentication. SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2017

I have two SQL Servers on different domains. I am trying to connect to SQL server "A" using SSMS on  domain "B", but getting this error.
`Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with integrated authentication. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error 18452).` 
Please help.

Comment: Sounds like you need to talk to your domain admin, get a trust set up between the domains.  Or maybe switch to a SQL Login since it's not dependent on domains and thus won't have that issue.

Comment: Possibly a double hop issue? Seem to recall something similar once there's an active directory option along the lines of require preuathentication you can try disabling, if memory serves.

Comment: What is the setup? Are the two machines on the same domain, or any domain at all (rather than a workgroup/Home setup)? If they are on the same domain, are you double-hopping via Remote Desktop or similar?

Comment: This error can be returned when the account is disabled or the password is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you state the servers are in different domains ... the first comment from @squillman gives the answer. You must do one of the following:

1. establish a domain trust between the domains
2. <s>Create an identical local (non-domain) user on each server, and use that in your connectionstring</s> *per @Charlieface, this won't work.*
3. switch to a SQL login rather than using a Windows account

Comment: *"2. Create an identical local (non-domain) user on each server, and use that in your connectionstring"* This doesn't work, as Integrated Security ignores the connection string username. You would need to do impersonation, and hope that the password hash matches on both machines

Comment: @Charlieface thanks, I've edited the answer accordingly.